# Which directory to put color schemes?

Tags: neovim

In vim, I can put color schemes inside `~/.vim/colors/` folder. Where should I put color schemes so that NeoVim can pick them up?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The directory is `~/.config/nvim/colors`.

Answer (score 12):

For Windows it's `%UserProfile%\AppData\Local\nvim\colors`.